# Label and jQuery click event firing in reverse order

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, label

I have an interactive form with multiple steps and in several instances, there is a button, which moves the form a step further, and is also a HTML `<label>` for `<input type="radio">`. The problem is, that when a user clicks the button, I need the `<label>` click event (selecting a hidden radio button) to fire first and then the jQuery (since the next step is dependent on which radio input is selected.

Is there a way in jQuery to wait for the `<label>` click event to happen and then fire itself?

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="option1" id="radio1">
<label for="radio1">Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="option2" id="radio2">
<label for="radio2">Option 2</label>
```

```
$('label').click(function(){ //this fires before the label checks the radio

  //need to wait here

  if ($('#radio1').prop('checked')) {
   //open step 1
  } else {
   //open step 2
  }
});
```

Comment: What about `$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){ /* this fires when you change the value of the radios */ })`?

Comment: it was shortened for the purpose of this question, there is a more global function that is also connected to the labels, therefore it would be great to listen to the click

Comment: Move your logic `open step 1/2` in the radio change event so, you are not obligated to put all the code in the label click, aren't you? Click event fires before the change event by the way, so I don't think you will catch that in there

Comment: I probably won’t have another way to do this, but as I said, the label is a button, that is in the whole form several more times, not always being a label, but a <div> or a <button> and the jQuery function is written globally for all of the buttons that move the form a step forwards. I can technically make separate event listener for the change, was just looking for an easier way tho.

Comment: you can use preventDefault(); ?

Comment: @MeghshyamSonar how exactly would I do so? It might be possible, I can’t seem to make out how’d you do it...

Comment: $('label').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();}); give it a try

Comment: @MeghshyamSonar I think that would do the opposite of that I need - I need the label default event (checking the radio) to happen first AND THEN the jQuery click event. Preventing default would not change anything.

Comment: you can check if that `checkbox` is checked or not before going to next and if its not checked just  show some alert message .

Comment: @Swati that would decrease conversion rate and fluidness for the user